# Running a simulation/reversion to the mean without the mean

Tags: r

I'm trying to answer this question but I'm not sure how I can get the mean to get started:

Perform a fake-data simulation as in Section 6.5, but using
the flight school example on page 89. Simulate data from 500 pilots, each of whom performs
two maneuvers, with each maneuver scored continuously on a 0–10 scale, that each pilot has a true ability that is unchanged during the two tasks, and that the score for each test is equal to this
true ability plus independent errors. Further suppose that when pilots score higher than 7 on
the scale during the first maneuver, they get praised and that scores lower than 3 on the
first maneuver result in negative reinforcement. Also suppose, though, that this feedback has no
effect on performance on the second task.

(a) Make a scatterplot with one dot for each pilot, showing score on the second maneuver vs.
score on the first maneuver. Color the dots blue for the pilots who got praised, red for those
who got negative reinforcement, and black for the other cases.

I'm trying to run a reversion to the mean but I need the mean. I'm not sure if I'm suppose to use the 7 and 3 as the mean here or run another simulation to get the mean.

Comment: It's not clear what the independent errors are supposed to be here.

Comment: My guess is that the intended mean is 5 (perhaps that was discussed on the mysterious page 89). There are infinitely many possible distributions of the errors (even if one were to assume normal with mean 0, the standard deviation is unspecified). Is there some sort of context that you aren't telling us about?